# Userform MultiPage Navigation

Tags: vba, excel

I have a Userform I built in Excel that has roughly ten tabs utilizing the MultiPage setup. Problem is I am running out of space for additional tabs and would really like to replace the tabs with a friendlier Navigation Menu or Toolbar. I've looked into the Microsoft ToolBar Control, which is close to what I'm looking for but I can't change the height and the dropdown has to have the arrow clicked and nto the text, which is not that intuitive in my opinion.

So my question is, are any of you familiar with a better multipage navigation setup, perhaps using a form of ActiveX?

Answer (score 1):

I would reccommend seperating your User Form into seperate forms or Child forms based on category.
You can have one form launch another one if they are both Modeless, and both can be on screen at the same time. This way, you can work with both consecutively.

To launch a form as modeless, when you do `Form1.Show` change it to `Form1.Show vbModeless`

Comment: Yeah that's a great thought, which I've thought about doing.. I'm just not ready to commit to segmenting it like that yet lol. I've been trying to do research for the past half hour trying to find a solid solution to making Navigation and can't find anything. I tried to mess with the actual Ribbon in Excel but didn't really care for that.

Comment: so  here is an interesting idea.. I ended up using a FlexGrid and populating it via my database, and changing the background color to match the background of the Userform. Now it feels familiar to the way I'd layout a website.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was making a Listbox with all my different pages that is apart of my Multipage then placed this listbox on the left hand side of my Userform then used this code

Populate the listbox

```
    i = 0
    With Main_Window.form_navigation_list
            .AddItem "Domestic"
                .List(i, 0) = "Page 1"
                .List(i, 1) = 0
        i = i + 1
            .AddItem
                .List(i, 0) = "Page 2"
                .List(i, 1) = 1
        i = i + 1
End With
```

Then I have this for the on click

```
Private Sub form_navigation_list_Click()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim SelectedRow As Integer

        For SelectedRow = 0 To Main_Window.form_navigation_list.ListCount - 1
            If Main_Window.form_navigation_list.Selected(SelectedRow) Then
                nav_page = Main_Window.form_navigation_list.List(SelectedRow, 1)
                With Main_Window
                    .MultiPage1.Value = nav_page
                    .Show
                End With
            End If
        Next

End Sub
```

I started off using a flexgrid but kept getting a memory leak issue and program would crash, so I swapped to the listbox and it's working fine now. Now I can customize this listbox to look a bit more like the navigation I want.